# How can i show just integer labels?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

My chart has 100 labels. These labels are from 0 to 10. Some labels are decimal. But i just want to see integers on my chart. How can i hide decimals? You can check my picture and code below.

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O04Nv.png)

```
var timeLabels = [];

for (let j = 0; j <= scheduling.totalPeriod; j++) {
  timeLabels.push(j / 10);
}

var schedulingChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: timeLabels,
    datasets: [{
      steppedLine: true,
      label: scheduling.process[i].name,
      data: scheduling.process[i].chart,
      backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)'],
      borderColor: ['rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)'],
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointBackgroundColor: 'green',
      pointBorderColor: 'black',
      pointRadius: 4
    }]
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
        },
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 1,
          fontColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)'
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
        },
        ticks: {
          fontColor: 'white',
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

[New for other problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFF20.png)

Comment: You can remove the decimal data from data set but if its about showing the labels on chart then use ticks on axes labelling to return ' ' if value is decimal.https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html

Comment: Just do the same as you did for the y-axis, also define `ticks.stepSize: 1` for the x-axis.

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan Thank you. I did by using callback function. I have a new problem. My chart just shows integer it is perfect. But it miss some integer labels. If there is a lot of labels it is normal. My chart has area to show all of them how can fix? I want to see 1,2,3,4,5,6......19,20. You can check new image to understand well. Thank you again for your answer it solved my problem.

Comment: Try changing the styling for labels such as lineHeight and padding. You can check the documentation in the same link. The default padding for labels is 4. Setting it 0 may show all the labels.